# Are there any mentions of Torah Scrolls before Ezra?

Tags: tanach, sefer-torah, navi-prophets

Ezra the Scribe famously discovered a Torah Scroll and instituted public Torah readings on Shabat, Monday, and Thursday.

Are there any mentions of Torah Scrolls (specifically *written*) between Moshe and Ezra?

Comment: Can you source the "famous" claims in your first sentence?

Comment: Do you count mention of the Torah _as_ written (plentiful, see for instance Melachim 1 2:3, "as it is _written_ in the Torah of Moshe") or do you only want people physically interacting with the scrolls themselves?

Comment: see Gittin 60........

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Melachim (Kings) [Chapters 22-23](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15928), King Joshiahu discovers a Torah scroll during renovations of the Temple.

Comment: it would be nice to have more examples...

Comment: @sds Why would you think there are so many examples? The scrolls probably sat in the study halls and were used for study. The stories in the Neviim don't talk about people just sitting and studying all that often.

Comment: Which lettering was used in that scroll, do we know?

Answer (score 6):

In Divrei haYamim II [17:9](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Chronicles.17.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), King Yehoshafat sends out people to teach Torah in the land of Yehuda and they take physical Torah scrolls with them.